NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/jdbc/JDBCContext
I am asked to run a spring boot application inside a java web application that doesn't use a dependency management tool so i am running my spring-boot-app without an embedded tomcat the issue was when i tried to use hibernate 5 it seems that the project is dependant on hibernate 3 such as org/hibernate/jdbc/JDBCContext
I need a way to use both hibernate versions since it is not possible to refactor the old code due to security issues in the company
I am using spring-boot-1.5.22RELEASE
with spring 4.3.25.RELEASE
my spring boot app is running fine but the other source folders are having this issue
2024-04-30 16:35:45.087  INFO 17672 --- [ost-startStop-1] e.c.c.clsStaticData                      : decrypt failed for "NAJM_PORTAL" perhaps value isn't crypted...
%xwExException in thread "ITC WorkerThread - System pool - Group SystemDefault - Thread 1" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/jdbc/JDBCContext
    at es.cls.core.service.ServiceManager$ServiceState.run(ServiceManager.java:483)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at es.cls.threadpool.ESFutureTask$Sync.innerRun(ESFutureTask.java:455)
    at es.cls.threadpool.ESFutureTask.run(ESFutureTask.java:279)
    at es.cls.threadpool.ESThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ESThreadPoolExecutor.java:807)
    at es.cls.threadpool.ESThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ESThreadPoolExecutor.java:835)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.jdbc.JDBCContext
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1415)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1223)
    ... 7 more

project structure
used hibernate jars

Does this answer your question? Why am I getting a NoClassDefFoundError in Java?

i understand the reason of NoClassDefFoundError my issue is that i have classes dependant on a class found in hibernate 3 and i am adding spring boot which is dependant on versions of hibernate where the class org/hibernate/jdbc/JDBCContext is removed and i am not able to refactor the old code
